# Seconds of constant funk

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

This is a themed cryptic crossword, with five answers sticking to the theme.

[image]

> **ACROSS**
> 2/29d. Guitarist for 20-down (or Radiohead), content in retiring, achieved $1000 (4, 4)
> 4. Reactions of surprise following sound of explosion in ceremonies (7)
> 8/27d. Golf game beginning with an event of food and tea for the audience (3, 4)
> 11. Josh goes back to golf hole, ending with a light push (5)
> 12. Even before Christ shelters man (7)
> 13/1d. Within trip; it's to pause! (3, 4)
> 14. Red part appears in beryl's center facets irregularly, causes change in direction of light (8)
> 15. Nothing ever ends/changes, to English philosopher (4)
> 18. (See 17-down)
> 19. Entering Senegal's south initially, extremist having gun lurks (6)
> 21. Greatly destroy capital having no symbol (4, 2)
> 22. Intervene in haste, pinning prisoners (4, 2)
> 25. Back to award lacking width or depth? (4)
> 26. Poor hero's dressed, going to the sea (8)
> 28. Recalling episode, finally withdraw from seat (3)
> 30. Spanning Swedish author's exempla at first (7)
> 31. T-Rex mutilated a person in the background of show (5)
> 32. Run in Scottish parish in the middle north (3)
> 33. Biologist and pseudoscientist to induce dissolution with no infusion of potassium (7)
> 34. Iranian guy who lost fiancée visits yours truly (4)

> **DOWN**
> 1. (See 13-across)
> 2. Curt men ordered a certain brand of multivitamins (7)
> 3. Refined new composition in the key of G, changing meaning (10)
> 5. Robot's left with unit of information within; confined in zero gravity like a satellite around Earth? (8)
> 6. Wizard John's defense? (4)
> 7. Primarily old, degrading ruins, interspersed, points to a group of historical places briefly (7)
> 9. Saved tattered writings (5)
> 10. British aircraft are unnaturally overpowered way after (9)
> 16. Before noon on both sides of street/road, surrounding eastern capital (9)
> 17/18a. Anticipate time of event, a desire about it: for them to bring back genre of music (4, 3, 3, 6)
> 20. Rhythm section becoming prominent from the fifth EP, "False Album": every second of it brought about constant funk, at last! (8)
> 21. Possessing immense power, with respect to besieging east and west of Lithuania (7)
> 23. Appear excited without a single note to ready up (7)
> 24. In Athens' west, stone bulwark ultimately turning crooked (5)
> 27. (See 8-across)
> 29. (See 2-across)

---

<sub>*P.S. In addition, I have thought about one clue for a while, because it uses a method of cluing that many may perceive as unfair. However, I really want to preserve its surface reading. To the Ximenean adherents more devout than I am, please don't burn me alive for this :(( I promise, though, that, in the future, whenever I use this method of cluing again, I will make use of much fairer examples. (For now though, to be kinder, I will say that the clue needs **two spaces** for the cluing to be at its fairest, though the surface reading be ruined.)*</sub>

<sub>*P.P.S. I am aware of the three consecutive unchecked cells in 10-down and 16-down. I will also make sure to not repeat this next time.*</sub>

<sub>*P.P.P.S. The blue colors are just for aesthetics. I'm tired of seeing crosswords all black and white :P*</sub>

<sub>*P.P.P.P.S. Finally, this is my second try at cryptic clues, but the first at cryptic crosswords. Do provide feedback, especially if I have erred in cluing methods.*</sub>

Comment: [This is the grid in plaintext.](https://pastebin.com/5bmvU8Hj)

Comment: I started this but I'm heading off early for the night. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7NuX.png)'s my progress (along with a few notes on clues).

Comment: Oh no, I discovered a slight ambiguity in one clue. Edited accordingly, and apologies again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finished grid

> [image]

Clue explanations

> ```
> -- ACROSS --
>  2/29d. CO(R)Y+WON+G             Guitarist for 20-down (or Radiohead), content in retiring, achieved $1000 (4,4)
>  4. POW+WOWS                     Reactions of surprise following sound of explosion in ceremonies (7)
>  8/27d. TEE TIME ~tea time       Golf game beginning with an event of food and tea for the audience (3,4)
>  11. NUD<+G+_E                   Josh goes back to golf hole, ending with a light push (5)
>  12. B(ALAN)CE                   Even before Christ shelters man (7)
>  13/1. _P IT'S TO P_             Within trip; it's to pause! (3,4)
>  14. _R_+EF(R)ACTS*              Red part appears in beryl's center facets irregularly, causes change in direction of light (8)
>  15. Z(er > EN)O                 Nothing ever ends/changes, to English philosopher (4)
>  19. SN(E_+AK)S                  Entering Senegal's south initially, extremist having gun lurks (6)
>  21. BANGUP (bang-up minus dash) Greatly destroy capital having no symbol (4,2)
>  22. _STE PIN_                   Intervene in haste, pinning prisoners (4,2)
>  25. RE(-w)AR(-d)                Back to award lacking width or depth? (4)
>  26. OFF+SHORE*                  Poor hero's dressed, going to the sea (8)
>  28. PE<+_W                      Recalling episode, finally withdraw from seat (3)
>  30. ASTRID+E_                   Spanning Swedish author's exempla at first (7)
>  31. EXTR*+A                     T-Rex mutilated a person in the background of show (5)
>  32. _RI_+N                      Run in Scottish parish in the middle north (3)
>  33. LYSE+N(K)O                  Biologist and pseudoscientist to induce dissolution with no infusion of potassium (7)
>  34. M(ED)E                      Iranian guy who lost fiancée visits yours truly (4)
>  
>  -- DOWN --
>  2. CENTRUM*                     Curt men ordered a certain brand of multivitamins (7)
>  3. REDEFIN*+IN+G                Refined new composition in the key of G, changing meaning (10)
>  5. O(R_+BIT+IN)G                Robot's left with unit of information within; confined in zero gravity like a satellite around Earth? (8)
>  6. WALL ddef.                   Wizard John's defense? (4)
>  7. W(O_)N(D_)E(R_)S             Primarily old, degrading ruins, interspersed, points to a group of historical places briefly (7)
>  9. VEDAS*                       Saved tattered writings (5)
>  10. AER*+OP+LANE                British aircraft are unnaturally overpowered way after (9)
>  16. AM+ST+E+RD+AM               Before noon on both sides of street/road, surrounding eastern capital (9)
>  17/18a. WA(IT+FOR+THEM+OME<)NT  Anticipate time of event, a desire about it: for them to bring back genre of music (4,3,3,6)
>  20. V+(_U_L_+F+PE)<+C+_K        Rhythm section becoming prominent from the fifth EP, "False Album": every second of it brought about constant funk, at last! (8)
>  21. B(EAST+L_)Y                 Possessing immense power, with respect to besieging east and west of Lithuania (7)
>  23. PREPA(-a)*+RE               Appear excited without a single note to ready up (7)
>  24. A+S(_K+_E)<+W             In Athens' west, stone bulwark ultimately turning crooked (5)
> ```

The themed entries

> "Cory Wong" (2a/29d), "Tee Time" (8a/27d), "Wait for the Moment" (17d/18a) and "Beastly" (21d) are all songs by Vulfpeck (20d).

Some clarifications

> 11a refers to musician [Josh Dun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josh_Dun).
>  In 30a, the Swedish author is [Astrid Lindgren](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrid_Lindgren).
>  In 34a, "guy who lost fiancée" is Ed Brown from the reality show *[90 Day Fiancé](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/90_Day_Fianc%C3%A9)*.
>  In 6d, "Wizard John" is [John Wall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wall_(basketball)) of the Washington Wizards.
>  In 7d, the "points" are compass points (west, north, east, south)
>  In 24d, "Athens" needs to be read "A, then S". This is the clue mentioned in the P.S. which needs two spaces.

Credits

> I looked at Deusovi's partial for 10 down. OP's comment helped with 6 down.
>  Fixed my explanations for 19a, 21a, 34a and 24d based on OP's comments.

Comment: :) I will explain some of the clues later; I will assist you first on the missing clue. rot13(Wbua vf n onfxrgonyy cynlre.)

Comment: rot13(19n: Frartny'f gjb-yrggre VFB pbqr vf FA. FAF pbagnvavat RNX. 21n: onat hc = onat-hc (pncvgny zrnavat "svefg-pynff"/"svir-fgne" (eryvrq ba Zreevnz Jrofgre sbe guvf)) jvgubhg qnfu flzoby. 34n: Rq Oebja sebz 90-Qnl Svnaprr (gubhtu, va ergebfcrpg, rira gubhtu gurer rkvfgf pbagebirefl ertneqvat uvz va gur cnfg srj zbaguf, V fubhyq abg unir rkcrpgrq gung znal jvyy xabj gur fubj, yrg nybar jub ur vf :(( ). RQ va ZR. 24q: NFJ pbagnvavat erirefrq RX.)

Comment: Ahh, I now see. It's the one that needs two spaces: rot13(n gura f).

Comment: @oAlt Ah ok, now I see it. I had read the PS's but had already forgotten about that remark.

Comment: Oh, nice to see you identified the theme and the thematic answers as well.